# Blank screen/JS error on new odoo installation after creating database

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I've installed Odoo (version 8.0) on an Ubuntu 14.04 server. Pretty much out of the box (I only set the admin password), I can create databases, but when I try to do anything else, I just get a mostly-blank screen and a Javascript error (`openerp.init is not a constructor` in Firefox, `undefined is not a function` in Chrome/Safari). The "settings" menu option does show up, but does not do anything (obviously, given the fact that the Javascript doesn't work).

The database *does* get created (I can see it in the postgres database). The login screen also shows up (but logging in gives me the same error again), and the 'manage databases' link on it does still work. I can create additional databases, drop them, all of that works. I just can't actually *do* anything with the databases.

I've looked around in the Odoo documentation, but I can't find anything. Looking online for the error itself, I only get people who've caused this by installing add-ons (I didn't), or who say you can fix this by dropping the databases (it doesn't work), or using a different browser (none of Safari, Firefox, and Chrome work).

It also sometimes simply hangs trying to load one of the Javascript files (with names like `web/js/web.assets_backend/fa4f621`).

Information:

- [odoo-server.conf](https://gist.github.com/marinuso/fb90738ab15c4b192aa0)
- [log file](https://gist.github.com/marinuso/51a4ef90d713fa38eb2f)
- [screen shots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD6Sc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a time ago and I had solved that this way:

Check that you're executing the Odoo service using the file `odoo.py` (do not execute `openerp-gevent` neither `openerp-server`). In your browser, remove all the cookies stored at the URL you're using for Odoo, and then, restart the service:

```
sudo fuser -k your_port/tcp
python your_odoo_path/odoo.py -c your_config_file_path --update=all -d your_database_name
```

Comment: Does it happen to you in any port (if you switch to other one) and in any database?

Comment: Changing the port somehow gained me a database selector in the login screen (with all the names of the databases I've tried to create actually in there), but I still can't actually get at anything. As for the database, I haven't even been able to properly create one, as the screen goes blank after I click the "create" button. It doesn't seem to matter what name I use or what I pass to `-d`, or whether I even use `-d` at all. It *does* connect to the Postgres instance correctly, as I can see the databases I've tried to create in there (and also in the login screen).

Comment: I've figured out the login details, but logging in just gives me the same error.

Comment: Sometimes you have to wait a moment for it to work. I think it's related to rebuilding the cache (`/filestore`)

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue with a production install of Odoo. It seems to be a mixture of issues all collaborating together. Here are the steps I followed (I'm not 100% sure if all steps are required):

- Clear browser cookies/cache/local website data on local machine's browser (clearing cache only did not work).
- Delete (and backup!) session data from `/opt/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/sessions`
- Complete reinstall of Odoo (re-cloning Odoo from github did not work - I had to launch a new AWS instance).
- I suspect it might also be possible to 'clean' the postgres databases if you'e uncomfortable with a full reinstall.

This is an old topic but I'm posting here for future reference.

Just for clarity's sake, my issue was caused by one of our staff members refreshing the browser while in the Odoo POS. There were no errors in the log file, and resulted in the behavior seen in OP's screenshots. It seems that a session was corrupted, then stored in the database somehow.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit late for this answer but for future users reading... This seems to be an Odoo unsolved issue (happened to me with Odoo 12). There is a few ("official") workarounds from the issue thread on GitHub (you don't need to reinstall everything!!):

1- quick fix: DELETE FROM ir_attachment WHERE url LIKE '/web/content/%';

2- If it doesn't work, try cleaning browser cache and retry.

3- If it doesn't work, just delete the db and postgresql user and recreated it.

Recreating the DB usually works.

I now all of this are workarounds, but so far, this issue haven't been solved by Odoo team.

You can [track the issue on GitHub](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/13808)